# How do I have hyper v on windows 10 load all screens after leaving the vm window and returning from the host?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

When I connect to Hyper-V from Hyper-V manager on Windows 10 Pro I check the box to use all monitors, and it loads as expected. When I minimize that windows to do something in the Host and the maximize it again it stays within one display (the laptop's display) and does not expand to the other monitors. Additionally, it shows scrollbars and shows all four screens within the single scrollable window.

I did not have this problem on my previous windows 10 laptop so I expect it is something I can resolve through settings or configuration. Can you help?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of Windows are you running within the VM?  What version of Windows were you running on your laptop?

Comment: I am running windows 10 pro on the host and vm for the previous and current laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable enhanced session for this VM?

[image]

Please also check [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/cffa1656-1e51-4e95-ad50-42d6690ee5f0/cross-post-resize-window-frame-and-not-its-contents?forum=winserverhyperv) which discussed a similar situation as yours if it helps.

Comment: My settings look different. I don't have that item. I edited my post to include a screenshot.

Comment: There are very specific requirements for enhanced sessions, does  it appear, the author’s configuration satisfy those requirements

Comment: @Ramhound What?